# PHP SQL Sorting information into HTML div elements

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sort SQL results into different divs based on the category they are assigned in the database. There are four categories and it works fine as long as there are videos available for all 4 categories. It will create 1 div for each and assign the videos to the correct div. The issue I'm having is that I'd like to also create the div even if there are no videos available within that category. (Pretty new so the code is probably pretty chunky for what it should be)

**PHP code**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM VIDEOS WHERE categorie=:category ORDER BY categorie ASC, subcategorie ASC");
$stmt->bindParam(':category', $_POST['category']);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<div class='spacer'>";

$testcase = "";
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($result); $x++) {
    if($result[$x]["subcategorie"] != $testcase) {
        echo    
            "</div><div class='subcategory_container active' id='" . $result[$x]["subcategorie"] . "'>
            <h3 class='subcategory_title'>". $result[$x]["subcategorie"] . "</h3>";
        echo 
            "<div class='video_div'> <iframe width='196' height='350'
            src='" . $result[$x]['linkembed'] . "'>
            </iframe></div>"; 
        $testcase = $result[$x]["subcategorie"];
    } else {
        echo 
            "<div class='video_div'> <iframe width='196' height='350'
            src='" . $result[$x]['linkembed'] . "'>
            </iframe></div>";    
    }
}
```

I have tried adding multiple `if($result[$x]["subcategorie"] == "categoryname")` statements but specifying the name within a for loop resulted in there being multiple of the same divs and a repeat of data. So far I've tried to look up SQL group by PHP tutorials but they all show the same result being inside of a table. The goal is to get the information into their own div with the ID of said div being the category name. I'm working with AJAX calls using JS to fix the issue won't work.

Comment: So check if `sizeof($result)` is 0, and if so, output an empty div then?

Comment: The sizeof works when there's no results. Then I can manually add 4 divs with the categories. However the problem is when there are for example videos within 2 categories. This would create 2 relevant categories and the 2 unused categories would not create an empty associated div.

Comment: You are passing a specific category as a POST parameter here, so I had assumed you are making four separate AJAX requests here - in which case this should work fine. But apparently you are doing something else - so please clarify.

Comment: The AJAX request is made when clicking a li (to select the category). Once the category is selected it is updated as the $POST. Utilizing this I SQL call all videos within the category. They have either one of four subcategories assigned to them ("kracht", "uithouding", "mobiliteit',"stretching") I'm trying to create 4 divs with the subcategory as ID and populate with the relevant videos. This currently works if every subcategory is present. When one or more are missing should still create the div with category ID but it should be empty within.

Comment: Ah, so this is about the _subcategories_ - you did not actually mention that in your question. Easiest solution: Loop over an array containing your four subcategories, to create your divs. And inside, loop over your query result - and only output the elements, where the subcategory matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution builds a `$videos` array using the static subcategories as keys, it then populates these after looking through the database, then it's a matter of echoing the iframes if records exist.

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Terhert
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: PHP SQL Sorting information into HTML div elements
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715867/php-sql-sorting-information-into-html-div-elements
Tags: php, mysql

*/

include '../../inc/helpers.php';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_OPTIONS);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$pdo->query('DROP TABLE table74715867;');
$pdo->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table74715867 (id TEXT, name TEXT, linkembed TEXT, categorie TEXT, subcategorie TEXT);');

$data = [
    ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'test1','linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => 'abc', 'subcategorie' => 'kracht'],
    ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'test2','linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => 'abc', 'subcategorie' => 'uithouding'],
    ['id' => '9', 'name' => 'test9','linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => 'abc', 'subcategorie' => 'mobiliteit'],
    ['id' => '10', 'name' => 'test10','linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => 'abc', 'subcategorie' => 'mobiliteit'],
    ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'test3','linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => 'xyz', 'subcategorie' => 'majig1'],
    ['id' => '4', 'name' => 'test4','linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => 'xyz', 'subcategorie' => 'majig2'],
    ['id' => '5', 'name' => 'test5', 'linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => '123', 'subcategorie' => 'whatchmacallit1'],
    ['id' => '6', 'name' => 'test6', 'linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => '123', 'subcategorie' => 'whatchmacallit2'],
    ['id' => '7', 'name' => 'test7', 'linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => 'qwerty', 'subcategorie' => 'fizz1'],
    ['id' => '8', 'name' => 'test8', 'linkembed' => 'http://example.org', 'categorie' => 'qwerty', 'subcategorie' => 'buzz1'],
];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table74715867 SET id=:id, name=:name, linkembed=:linkembed, categorie=:categorie, subcategorie=:subcategorie;');
foreach ($data as $record) {
    $stmt->execute([
        ':id' => $record['id'],
        ':name' => $record['name'],
        ':linkembed' => $record['linkembed'],
        ':categorie' => $record['categorie'],
        ':subcategorie' => $record['subcategorie']
    ]);
}

$category = 'abc';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table74715867 WHERE categorie=:category ORDER BY categorie ASC, subcategorie ASC");
$stmt->bindParam(':category', $category);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$videos = ["kracht" => [], "uithouding" => [], "mobiliteit" => [], "stretching" => []];
foreach ($result as $record) {
    $videos[$record['subcategorie']][] = $record;
}

foreach ($videos as $subcategory => $records) {
    echo '<div class="subcategory_container active" id="' . $subcategory . '">' . 
    '<h3 class="subcategory_title">' . $subcategory . '</h3>';
    if (!empty($records)) {
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            echo '<div class="video_div"><iframe width="196" height="350" src="'.$record['linkembed'].'"></iframe></div>';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Here's the resulting HTML:

```
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="subcategory_container active" id="kracht">
    <h3 class="subcategory_title">kracht</h3>
    <div class="video_div">
      <iframe src="http://example.org" width="196" height="350"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory_container active" id="uithouding">
    <h3 class="subcategory_title">uithouding</h3>
    <div class="video_div">
      <iframe src="http://example.org" width="196" height="350"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory_container active" id="mobiliteit">
    <h3 class="subcategory_title">mobiliteit</h3>
    <div class="video_div">
      <iframe src="http://example.org" width="196" height="350"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video_div">
      <iframe src="http://example.org" width="196" height="350"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcategory_container active" id="stretching">
    <h3 class="subcategory_title">stretching</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```